# C#: Singleton using a Singleton

Tags: c#, singleton

I have a curious question here. Is it wise to have a singleton class use or call another singleton class? The project the i'm currently working does this a quite a bit. The good and bad tidbits of this convention would be most helpful.

Comment: Why do you think there is anything wrong with that?

Comment: That always depends on the project. What do you want to do?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if there is or isn't. I want some insight and I guess I have never seen singles used so much before which prompts my curiosity.

Comment: Oh boy, that's a very broad question for current project that I'm working on.    Can't really go into detail, that would take several weeks to explain

Comment: It is only bad if it's a multi-threaded application with multiple threads that access the singletons if they're not static. At that point you'll need to sync or risk running into race conditions.

Comment: @RichardBarker And that's only a problem if the singletons are not thread safe, if they don't do anything other than atomic operations then synchronization isn't needed. Again it depends on what the singletons do with each other.

Comment: @RichardBarker very good point. What would an good alternative? What do you mean by "sync"?

Comment: Synchronization is syncing a thread with an object so that only that thread has access to the object. Otherwise another thread might modify the object while this thread is trying to use it. But that's from my meager understanding of the thing. As @Ron said it only matters if the singletons aren't performing atomic operations and arent thread safe.

Comment: Ah I see gotcha. Thank you all for the insight :) It was much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no point about it. Each singelton stands for itself and call the other or not. It's not good or bad.

It depens on your goal, if the singeltons themself are a good decission.

Comment: Given this example: Client Server app. Say the Sign on and Auth methods server side are singletons. Sign On accesses Auth. How would this affect performance? Would cause deadlocks to occur?

Comment: @JosephFreeman Methods aren't really "singleton", they can be static or instance. Types (classes) themselves can be constructed singleton so that only one **instance** of them exists. Its like when you want the benefits of an instance class and force only one to ever be created. Static is a little different.

Comment: Can you provide code, at least simplyfied, to get the idea?